# How to route audio through bluetooth headphones on Android 4.0.3 rooted tablet

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, headphones

**BACKGROUND**
Newbie to Android. Taught myself some programming in the past (HTML, Java, javascript, some C++ etc). Bought my first Android device, a Zenithink C71 7" tablet (from China). It is rooted and running Android 4.0.3. It has no USB connections, just 2 firewire ports, one marked Host, the other marked Dev. I bought a firewire/USB adapter and can plug a Belkin USB bluetooth dongle into the Host firewire port on the tablet to add bluetooth devices. Some devices work fine e.g. bluetooth mouse. My problem is getting my bluetooth headphones to work. The headphones offer both mono audio for phone use and stereo AD2P. The headphones work perfectly with my phone and laptop it is just with the tablet that things go wrong. According to the settings manager on the tablet, the headphones are detected, paired, connected, and the system reports they are operational and media audio is being routed through them. But, bizarrely, the audio continues to play through the tablet's speakers and not the headphones. However, if I turn off the headphones the tablet audio stops playing. The headphones are working as a remote control switch and not as headphones(!) I am at a loss to understand what is going on but I hope it is something I might correct by resetting some code or writing a little app to manage bluetooth audio. I have joined the forum to get some help with this project -- and if I get hooked on Android then I hope I will start developing some apps too.

**QUESTIONS**
Can anyone reading this suggest a possible cause for my problems and thus point me in the right direction to find a solution?

- Is the issue likely to be due to hardware or software problems?
- If software, is this an issue with Android 4.0.3 or the manufacturer's firmware?
- If Android, where in the Android folders on my tablet do I need to
  look to check the coding to control bluetooth audio?
- Once I have a copy of the coding running my tablet, where on-line do I
  look for examples of how the coding *should be* in order to run
  bluetooth? (I am hoping it is a case of comparing my tablet's coding with a
  'specimen book' and then rewriting my tablet to manage the routing so
  I can enjoy audio through my bluetooth headphones.)

It might be a long project but if anyone can start me off on the first step then I would be very grateful -- and I expect my experiences will be interesting to other Zenithink owners trying to do the same on their tablets. I will be sure to report back if/when I solve this problem.

With many thanks for your help.